# C# dynamic class get property by atttibutes

Tags: c#

I use C# to communicate with my Xiaomi gateway.

When I receive message from gateway,  I send it to my home automation and save it to dictionary.

For example, to retrieve data I use :

```
dynamic test = Equipements[data.Model][data.Sid].Report;
```

When I test the type, it's ok. Now I need to retrieve property of this class by attribute. So I use JSONproperty like this :

```
public class MagnetReport
{
    [JsonProperty("voltage")]
    public int Voltage { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

I need to find Voltage by voltage. I try :

```
var res = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                                    .Where(
                                        p =>
                                            (p.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>() ?? new JsonPropertyAttribute()).Value == value.Value);
```

But everytime I've got an error "Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type"

I think it's because test is dynamic but I can't know his type, it depend the equipment that send the message.

Is it possible to do this with `dynamic`?

Comment: can you add .ToList or FirstOrDefault at the end and try--

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing here.  If you have an instance of `MagnetReport`, then just use `report.Voltage`.  Why are you accessing the properties via reflection?

Comment: It's because I don't know if it's magnet or else sensor. I only know the type when I receive command.

Comment: A couple of questions I should have asked first. 1) What part test plays in your LINQ query? Is it `var type = typeof(test);`? 2) What is `value`? 3) Are you trying to get value of a certain property from `test`?

Comment: This code came from stack overflow, someone else do this but it doesn't work with dynamic var.

Comment: I don't know if I explain well my property attribute is for example [JsonProperty("humidity")] and my property is public string Humidity. I have humidity so I need to find class property that have it as attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With updated information, it becomes

```
var value = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .FirstOrDefault(p => string.Compare(p.Name, propertyName, true) == 0)
            ?.GetValue(test, null);
```

Comment: It seems great but it says that JSONproperty doesn't contain definition for Value

Comment: Then it likely does not. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: My class has "temperature" as attribute (because my property name must be PascalCase so Temperature). When I receive informations with temperature, I must find the property Temperature so I'm looking for the property with JsonProperty("temperature") as attribute.

Comment: Sorry but how do you use it ? I think property name match the property name but test ? Attribute name ?